# How to add a key/custom key in default android keyboard

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to add an custom KEY or modify existing KEY in Android default keyboard.

I want to use that key only in my app.

how to do this? any link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to use this KEY in all Apps or only your own App?

Comment: @Calvin only in his app.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a walk-around. 
You can try to listen to key down event. Then for a particular key press, instead of original action, perform your action and tell android that you have handled it.

For example, press "Q", instead of insert an "Q", it should popup a dialog.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Q) {
        //popup dialog
    }
    return true; // Handled
}
```